# How to compute the speed of an area (raster data)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, speed

The raster data represent categorical zones (denoted by the colors). They moved over time. I would like to compute the speed of each zone  between two time periods i.e, distance of zone pink between period 1 and 2 over time.

I thought of:

1. Converting the raster to vector polygons
2. Calculating the centroid of each zone (polygons) for each period of time.
3. Calculating the distance between each zone (polygons).

Any other suggestions please?

[image]

Comment: Deleting a closed question and then asking it again he's not a good way to get a Question answered. It is a good way to provoke the StackExchange anti-spam defenses to sanction your account. Instead of reposting an unclear question, I suggest you edit it to be clearer.

Comment: Hello there, I reformulated the question already. I don't know how to make it more clear. If speed, raster data, polygons... and a thought about the method, is not clear enough... I don't know what to do then.

Comment: It's unclear to me because I can't see anywhere a definition of speed for categorical zones. How do they move over time? You should put at least one other image for a second period of time.

Comment: @BERA yes I do have the spatial analyst tool.

Comment: @xunilk The zones are defined by climatic, soil and terrain characteristics variables. Due to climate change simulations, they move. I did not post a picture of the second time period, because it's not that 'obvious' visually.  I thought of calculating the distance variable in the speed variable by accounting the difference in their area km2 from period 1 to 2 but in theory I need the shift of the border only... that is where I am stuck in my method.

Comment: So for example in your screenshot you want to measure the distance of the light red pixels to the darker red in the farthest north?

Comment: Hi BERA, in the second period the light red pixels might become darker red or the darker red might expand and become lighter (change of zone). That is what got me stuck. I don't know how to practically quantify all of this.

Answer (score 2):

Picture below shows 2 rasters - BEFORE and AFTER. I computed second by expanding zones 1 and 3 by 20 cells. Cell size is 5, so boundary of these zones moved by 100 m.

[image]

I used COMBINE tool from Spatial Analyst to locate changes, i.e. BEFORE<>AFTER:
[image]

And converted them to polygons (shown at first picture) and transferred values of before and after from combine raster using join field tool (see highlighted fields).
[image]

I also swap values in 2 fields to make sure BEFORE>AFTER (it doesn't matter if you do it other way around).
Finally I dissolved changes polygon using before and after as case fields and totals of length and area as statictics:

[image]

Width of polygons is zone shift. For skinny polygons it can be approximated as:

```
w = 2*area/perimeter
```

I used it to populate last field. As one can see answer is very close to ideal 100m.

If you want to know what zone is expanding and what is shrinking, do not swap values in changes table. Export table to excel and compute 2 pivot tables for area and perimeter totals. After is row name, before - column name. Do division in 3rd table.

Comment: Thank you Felix! I am not sure to understand everything but at the end the 100m has to be divided by the time period and I get my speed right? or does the software accounts for it directly?

Comment: Divide by time.

Comment: Hello Felix, I tried to follow your suggestions but I am not quite sure to be on the right path. Would you mind to exchange email and help through this?

Comment: What's your mail?